# Naming of a method that creates a list with new instances

Tags: java, methods, naming-conventions, naming, method-names

There's a method that creates a list of new instances from some parameters. I would call it this way:

```
List<NewType> createNewTypeInstances(OldType1 value1, OldType2 value2);
```

But I've also often seen it named in such a manner:

```
List<NewType> getNewTypeInstances(OldType1 value1, OldType2 value2);
```

My question is now: Should every method, that creates (or more generally: returns) something, be named with the prefix *get*?

Comment: Not easy to say, a matter of style. You may named it create* when it is an expensive method, get* if not. Add good docs to the method or explain your "style guide".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is poor style, and misleading, to have getters that:

- are not in fact "getters" (ie don't return a field of the instance)
- have side-effects (make any changes, to anything)

Your method fails on both points.

Calling it `create...` is a better choice, and a prefix often used for factory methods, to which your method is closely aligned.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should choose the name that best describes what the method does. Using get/set prefixes is an accepted convention to access properties of an object, but this method is not a getter.

I personally would use create, since the method creates things, and doesn't simply get them. But I would drop the "Instances" suffix, which adds needless noises. Every object is an instance of a class. Given what I know, I would thus probably name the method `createNewTypes()`.

That said, and without knowing anything about your software, `OldType` and `NewType` aren't really descriptive names.

Comment: OldType and NewType are just examples :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this method should be named `createNewTypeInstances`, because it is creating something. Method with `get` are by convention getters (accessor methods) and is job to return existing value, not to create new one.